# How can I create and show a list of articles and their advanced fields on a static page in Shopify Liquid?

Tags: shopify, liquid, custom-fields, shopify-liquid

I've developed a static site where I want to list blog articles and the content of their Accentuate metafields.

However I'm stuck and I can't get it going. I've tried to list the blog articles of that certain blog however it doesn't show up.

Can you help me out here please?

That's my code in Liquid

```
{%- assign allItems = blogs['kosmetikbehandlungen'].articles -%}
{%- for item in allItems -%}
 <p>{{ item.title }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```